# How to handle errors of observed values in multiple linear regression?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis

I am dealing with a multiple linear regression model such that
$$ E[Y] = \alpha + \beta X$$
I have a set of observations lets say

$$\bar{y}_i | x_{1i}, x_{2i}, ...$$
where $\bar{y}_i$'s are the measured values of the target variable $Y$ 
and $x_{ji}$'s are the measured inputs.

My problem is that measurements of $\bar{y}_i$'s had a certain error associated with them and I need to take that into consideration. Any idea how I could do that?

I asked a question before and got introduced to the concept of error-in-variables models. However, from what I understood that is related to the errors associated with $x_{ji}$'s and not $\bar{y}_i$'s.

Comment: By multivariate, do you mean multiple outcomes? Because that's what we usually describe as multivariate. It seems you are are referring to a single outcome variable. You can do weighted least squares (WLS), weighting the data by the measure of error you have. You can do WLS with almost all common statistical packages. OLS should still be unbiased, while WLS should be both unbiased and efficient.

Comment: If the "certain error" is expressed in terms of variances or standard deviations and if (as usual) the responses are independent, then your question is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/using-weighted-regression-to-obtain-fit-lines-for-which-i-only-have-summary-data/4144#4144.  Otherwise, could you fill us in on those details?

Comment: A structural equation model accounts for measurement error. Try starting with Kline (2015) and Rosseel (2012).

Comment: @user162986 thanks I changed the language of my post accordingly and am reading about WLS.

Comment: @whuber thank you I will be reading through it shortly.

Comment: @JaySchylerRaadt Thanks, I will read it shortly. The amount of citations that book has gotten is an indication of how useful it is though.